# MPMusicPlayerController volume deprecated - will an app using it be rejected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I've never known it to happen before where Apple have deprecated a function because they've changed their mind about allowing developers access to it.

I checked the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), and there's no mention of it there.

I'm curious - would an app be rejected for using this deprecated function, or is it simply deprecated because Apple may stop supporting it in the future, possibly in iOS 8, and thus current apps using it are fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the AppStore approval process and is best answered by Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's guidelines state that the app must be free from bugs, but deprecated references are not bugs. They merely come up as warnings in Xcode.

Since there's so much open source code out there Apple doesn't expect everyone to stop using deprecated methods/properties immediately. Typically they will leave deprecated elements accessible for one major release, then remove it from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Methods/Features are deprecated to discourage their usage. This simply means that there is now a better way to do it and the item marked as deprecated will soon be removed (probably in the next major release) and you should avoid using it.

Also, this doesn't mean your app will be rejected unless that feature has been marked deprecated for a long time.

Comment: So in the case of the volume property, what is the better way to do it?